# issue balancing constraints in Interface Builder when using ratio

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am having a problem with my constraints for an alert view I am building in interface builder.

[image]

[image]

When the screen is an iPhone 5 size I want the leading and trailing constraints to compress the images and make is smaller, I have a 1:1 ratio constraint set here too. This works great so far. However when the screen gets bigger e.g. iPhone7+ or iPad I want the image to remain the same size (that is the size of the image in interface builder, the iPhone7 size canvas). I have tried setting a constraint on the width of the image using `<=` and then setting the leading and trailing constraints on the image to priority `750`. This works for the bigger screens but now when I go back to the iPhone5 screen size it is broken because the priority on the leading and trailing constraints is less than that of the ratio. The image size remains unchanged. Seems no matter how I work the constraints I can only get the size working for a single scenario iPhone5 or iPhone6+. Has anyone had this kind of issue before? Any suggestions on how I can work the constraints??

Comment: Have you tried setting constraints using size classes?

Comment: no. how would I do that?

Comment: Got your solution @kex??

Comment: I disagree re size classes approach. Various iPhone devices are all the same class, namely compact width and regular height. The problem is that I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you can add snapshots of what it should look like on each size (adjusting them manually) and then we can advise what set of constraints or (gasp) code can achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring on size classes. Explore on this link. https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started.

Basically by using this you can set separate constraints to a same element with respect to size classes(which in term refers to different sizes of device screens).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it this way. It works well for iPhones of all sizes.

[image]

There are 3 key points regarding the `UIView` containing the image

- Set leading and trailing constraint as greater than or equal (>=)
- Center the view horizontally in the superview. This constraint combined with the previous ones will result in the view staying centered even when the image won't be able to stretch anymore.
- Set content hugging priority to required (1000).